# ADF Pipeline failure due to TypeError in Databricks notebook

Tags: azure-data-factory, typeerror, azure-databricks

I am running a ADF pipline that copies data from a DB to the Azure Blob store and then proceeds to initiate a Databricks notebook run.
The notebook fails with the message "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str".

However, when try to run the notebook manually (i.e., just hit "run all" on my notebook after the copy step), it works perfectly.

I am unable to understand why the pipeline fails at the notebook while the notebook runs perfectly fine.

Has anyone faced a similar problem? Does anyone know a fix to this?

TLDR; I tried running the Databricks notebook manually, and that worked. But the ADF pipeline fails to run it due to a TypeError. Do not know how to fix it.

Comment: What is the code you are running in notebook?

Comment: Are you passing any value from adf to notebook?

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

The above error arises when you concatenate an integer to string without converting it to that type like below.

[image]

Open the `runPageUrl` in the Notebook activity output, go to the error line and check if you are using any widgets in the error code. If you are using widgets, make sure you are passing the correct values (only strings) to the Notebook parameters from ADF notebook activity.

Also, use the same cluster in the notebook linked service which you are using in databricks notebook.

[image]

Use the existing cluster like above and check if it results the same.